# PL SQL String Manipulation (Deconcatenate based on multiple delimiters)

Tags: sql, string, plsql, split

I have string such as `A~B~C,D~E,F~G~H,I`. The string is comma separated and then each comma separated substring is `~` separated. There is no limit on the number of commas or `~` in a string. Objective is to get first value after each comma.

I am calling `coalesce` function to fetch number of commas.

```
select coalesce(length('A~B~C,D~E,F~G~H,I') - length(replace('A~B~C,D~E,F~G~H,I',',',null)), 
                length('A~B~C,D~E,F~G~H,I'),
                0) as output1 
  from dual;
```

Now, I want to run the loop for i = (output from coalesce query above) and substring the string based on comma and `~`. For example,

```
1st loop iteration - output = A
2nd loop iteration - output = D
3rd loop iteration - output = F
4th loop iteration - output = I
Loop Stops
```

I wrote this query which works fine except for the boundary cases i.e. fails in first iteration. Here `i` is the `i`th iteration of the loop

```
select substr('A~B~C,D~E,F~G~H,I',
       instr('A~B~C,D~E,F~G~H,I',',',1,i) + 1, 
       instr('A~B~C,D~E,F~G~H,I','~',1,1)-1) as output1 
  from dual;
```

Any suggestions? Ideas?

Comment: Are you doing any other processing on the primary or secondary parsed elements? As the answer as shown, just getting the 1st character after the comma is not too tough, but if you intend on further processing the approach will be different.

Comment: I am running a loop and updating a local variable with the output for each iteration of the loop. Also, the actual data consists of alphanumeric words and are not just letters as depicted. The local variable in turn is used as an input to another query and that is why it is important for it to have one value at a time.

Comment: So, you really want the first tilda-delimited list element of each comma-delimited list element?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @Gary_W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The natural way to solve this problem is using [Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm).

In the query below we apply expression `'(^|,)[A-Z]+'` to match a letter following after the beginning of string `^` or comma `,`. So `REGEXP_COUNT` lets limit the query results by exact count of matches in the string, and `REGEXP_SUBSTR` extracts exactly one match for each `LEVEL` from 1 to "matches count".

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.str, '(^|,)[A-Z]+', 1, LEVEL) AS substr
  FROM (
    SELECT 'A~B~C,D~E,F~G~H,I' AS str FROM DUAL
  ) T
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(T.str, '(^|,)[A-Z]+');
```

PS. As we see, resulting matches contain unneded commas. Not to overcomplicate the example the `REPLACE(result, ',')` is omitted.

Comment: Regarding the "PS": You could also group the relevant part to capture it and indicate which capture group you want: `REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.str, '(^|,)([A-Z]+)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 2)`

Comment: This works but I am storing the result in a local variable and would want the query to return only one character per iteration of the loop and then overwrite that result in every iteration of the loop. How can we modify this accordingly?

Comment: So put the query in a cursor then iterate the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT regexp_substr(
'UNB+UNOA,WT_Syntax_version_no+1:ZZ+2:ZZ+WT_Edi_sent_date:WT_Edi_sent_time+WT_Interchange_control_ref'
, '[^+|:|,]+' 
, 1
, LEVEL
) seq_no 
FROM dual
CONNECT BY regexp_substr('UNB+UNOA,WT_Syntax_version_no+1:ZZ+2:ZZ+WT_Edi_sent_date:WT_Edi_sent_time+WT_Interchange_control_ref','[^+|:]+', 1, LEVEL)
            IS NOT NULL;
```